# What kind of error in Binary search code?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am implementing the binary search tree with some operations ( new node, search, insert and display).
It results in following warning.

> ```
> binarytree.c:70: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a     cast
> binarytree.c:72: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
> binarytree.c:73: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
> binarytree.c: At top level:
> binarytree.c:78: warning: conflicting types for ‘printInoder’
> binarytree.c:47: warning: previous implicit declaration of ‘printInoder’ was here
> binarytree.c: In function ‘NewNode’:
> binarytree.c:122: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_newNode", referenced from:
>    _main in cckg2mll.o
>   _insert in cckg2mll.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

You will see my source code here below but I wish to hear your suggestions. I fully understand the Binary trees functions but I think it is not related to any algorithm but it is a programming problem.

**Source Code**

It is really long code but I cannot reduce it for your guys.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define false 0
#define true 1

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *left, *right;
}*node,*root;


int main(void)
{   
    root = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    int option = 1;
    int choice,value,target,newvalue;

    while(option)
    {
        printf("Enter your choice \n");
        scanf("%d\n",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
        printf("Enter the a new value\n");
        insert(root,value);
        scanf("%d\n",&value);
        break;

        case 2:
        printf("Enter the traget \n");
        scanf("%d\n",&target);
        lookup(root,target);
        break;

            case 3:
            printf("Enter the new node \n");
            scanf("%d\n",&newvalue);
            newNode();
            break;

            case 4:
            printInoder();
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter 0 or 1\n");
        scanf("%d\n",&option);
    }
}


int insert(struct Node *node ,int data) 
{
    // 1. If the tree is empty, return a new, single node
    node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if (node == NULL) 
    {
    return(newNode(data));
}

else 
{
    // 2. Otherwise, recur down the tree
    if (data <= node->data) 
        node->left = insert(node->left, data);
    else 
        node->right = insert(node->right, data);
    return(node); // return the (unchanged) node pointer
   }
  }

void printInoder()
  {

root = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

if (root != NULL)
{
    printInoder(root->left);
    printf("%d ",root->data);
    printInoder  (root->right);
   }
  }


   int lookup(struct Node *node, int target) 
   {
    node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   // 1. Base case == empty tree
   // in that case, the target is not found so return false
    if (node == NULL) 
   {
        return(false);
   }
    else 
    {
    // 2. see if found here
        if (target == node->data) return(true);

        else 
        {
   // 3. otherwise recur down the correct subtree
            if (target < node->data) 
                return(lookup(node->left, target));
           else return(lookup(node->right, target));
            }
   }
 }


struct Node *NewNode(int x) 
{
    node =(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); // "new" is like "malloc"
    node->data = x;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return(x);
  }
```

Comment: If the indentation of this code doesn't make you shudder in horror, you will never be a programmer. And we certainly won't go to the extra effort to decipher it before we can begin to help.

Comment: @Salem Alqahtani Declare all fiunctions that are used in main before main. I

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker Whether you work like a programmer or not does not depend on what code you write.:) It depends only whether is your boss is thoroughly  familiar. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the biggest issue is that you ignore data types. `insert` function returns `int` but whenever you assign its return value or even return something inside this function, the variables you use are pointers instead - so change return type of `insert` to `struct Node *node`.

Also, in `case 4` part, you use function `printInoder` which is declared and defined after calling it (below `main` function) so that is why it warns you that you should at least declare this function before `main`.

Finally, inside `insert` function, you call `newNode` but this function is called `NewNode` and it is also declared and defined below `main`.

Comment: Usually, it's the other way around :D

Answer (score 0):

You called the following function using `newNode` not `NewNode`. Also, move the `*` off of the `NewNode` part.

```
struct Node *NewNode(int x) 
{
    node =(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); // "new" is like "malloc"
    node->data = x;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return(x);
  }
```

Your `insert` function returns a node pointer but is declared with an `int` return type.

Also, you need to declare functions above where they are called the first time. add a declaration statement to the top of the page for your functions to work.

`return_type function_name(params);`

Finally, rename your function to `printInOrder()` instead of `printInoder()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many errors. 
I've edited it a bit:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define false 0
#define true 1

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *left, *right;
};

void insert(struct Node **node, int data);
int lookup(struct Node *node, int target);
void printInoder(struct Node *root);
struct Node *NewNode(int x);

int main(void)
{
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    int option = 1;
    int choice, value, target;

    while (option)
    {
        choice = value = target = 0;
        printf("Enter your choice \n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter the a new value\n");
            scanf("%d", &value);
            insert(&root, value);
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Enter the traget \n");
            scanf("%d", &target);
            printf("%d\n", lookup(root, target));
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("Printing\n");
            printInoder(root);
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("Enter 0 or 1\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);
    }
    return 0;
}


void insert(struct Node **root, int data)
{
    // 1. If the tree is empty, return a new, single node
    struct Node *node = NewNode(data);

    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        *root = node;
        return;
    }

    // 2. Otherwise, recur down the tree
    if (data <= (*root)->data)
        insert(&(*root)->left, data);
    else
        insert(&(*root)->right, data);
}

void printInoder(struct Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL) return;
    printInoder(root->left);
    printf("%d ", root->data);
    printInoder(root->right);
}


int lookup(struct Node *root, int target)
{

    // 1. Base case == empty tree
    // in that case, the target is not found so return false
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return(false);
    }

    // 2. see if found here
    if (target == root->data) return(true);

    // 3. otherwise recur down the correct subtree
    if (target < root->data)
        return(lookup(root->left, target));
    else return(lookup(root->right, target));
}


struct Node *NewNode(int x)
{
    struct Node *node= malloc(sizeof *node); 
    node->data = x;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

Try it, and take a look at the changes in the code.